# Safe_mode parameter not visible in phpinfo()

Tags: php

In order to install a certain piece of software I'm asked to check whether the `safe_mode` option is on or off through `phpinfo()`. However although I do see an option called `sql.safe_mode` there's no `safe_mode` option. Why not?